# How to express the meaning I mention in one formula?

Tags: logic

There are two points: $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$, if $|y_2-y_1|>|x_2-x_1|$ then  $\tan(A)=\frac{|y_2-y_1|}{|x_2-x_1|}$  else if $|y_2-y_1|<|x_2-x_1|$ then  $\tan(A)=\frac{|x_2-x_1|}{|y_2-y_1|}$

My question is, how to express the above meaning in one formula? what kind of Mathematical symbol should I use? thanks.

Comment: I think it is bad form to define $\tan(A)$. The function $\tan$ already has a specific meaning. It is better to use cases to define the angle $A$, then let $\tan$ have the usual meaning.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is better to define angle A.  Thanks. So, if I define angle A, how to express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I think it is bad form to overload the $\tan$ function.

If you are doing many trigonometric operations with this triangle, then it is best to clearly define all its parts. Doing so allows you to use cases to choose the appropriate *angle*, and then the trigonometric functions can have their usual meaning.

If you just need this one value, then forget about $\tan$ altogether and write something like:

> Let $a = \max\left(\dfrac{|x_2-x_1|}{|y_2-y_1|},\dfrac{|y_2-y_1|}{|x_2-x_1|}\right)$.

Comment: thank you, I think it is better to use this form.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan(A)=\dfrac{\max(|x_2-x_1|,|y_2-y_1|)}{\min(|x_2-x_1|,|y_2-y_1|)}$

Or:

$\tan(A)=\max\left(\dfrac{|x_2-x_1|}{|y_2-y_1|},\dfrac{|y_2-y_1|}{|x_2-x_1|}\right)$

where $\max(a,b)$ equals the greatest of $a$ and $b$

Comment: Thanks very much for your inspiration.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

$$\tan(A) = \begin{cases}
|y_2 - y_1| \ge |x_2 - x_1| &: \huge{\frac{|y_2 - y_1|}{|x_2 - x_1|}} \\ \\ \\
|y_2 - y_1| \le |x_2 - x_1| &: \huge{\frac{|x_2 - x_1|}{|y_2 - y_1|}} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, I want to express it in one formula using some Mathematical symbol, such as sign or some else. Do you have other method ? Thanks.